# How to setup ROS environment variable on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ros, ubuntu-20.04

I tried following [this](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu) guide to install ROS, but even after adding ROS source.list and its key

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

gave error.

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

Then I ran this command

```
sudo apt search ros
```

to see if any such package exists. I couldn't find `ros-melodic-desktop-full` but I found another similar package `ros-desktop-full`.
So I installed it instead. The installation went smooth without giving any errors.

Next step in the guide is to set-up ROS environment variable, but I have no such directory

```
/opt/ros
```

So how do I setup the environment variable?

**P.S.**

I also installed some tools and dependencies with this command

```
sudo apt install python3-rosdep python3-rosinstall python3-rosinstall-generator python3-wstool build-essential
```

and initialized `rosdep`

```
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation [here](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html), melodic is only supported on Ubuntu 18.04. The ROS version targeting Focal (20.04) is Noetic, but that one has not been released yet (see [Distributions](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions)). I'm not sure what ROS version Ubuntu packages (the `ros-desktop-full` one you installed), but I was not successful in using it.

If you really do want to use Ubuntu 20.04, then I think your best option currently is to compile from source. Last time I checked the precompiled debs for Noetic are not yet available at http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu (you can track release progress at [github issue 21513](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/21513)). No idea if compiling Noetic from source is easy or hard, but I was able to compile ROS2 foxy from source without too much trouble though.

Answer (score 3):

The `ros-desktop-full` package you installed is part of the official Ubuntu release.

ROS Melodic (and in the future, Noetic) is published by the [OSRF](https://www.openrobotics.org/) in a separate repository (`packages.ros.org`). These packages install to `/opt/ros/`. However, some ROS packages have also been ported to Debian, which is how they found their way to Ubuntu (which derives from Debian).

The Debian packages are fully functional, but they do not install to `/opt/ros`. Instead, everything is integrated in the operating system itself. This means that you need to set up your personal workspace slightly differently.

Given that most tutorials assume that you use the OSRF packages, I suggest you either wait for the Noetic release (scheduled for the end of May 2020), then install `ros-noetic-desktop-full`, or downgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to use ROS Melodic.